# SAP RAP Function DDIC Type as Import Parameter

Tags: odata, cds, sap-data-dictionary, rap

I am trying to create a OData function import via RAP.

When I use an abstract CDS view to define my parameter like this it works just fine:

```
static function XXX parameter YYY result [0..*] $self;
```

```
define abstract entity YYY
{
  importParameter: abap.string;

}
```

But since I only want a single importing parameter I thought about using a DDIC Type like it is implied in the [Cloud ABAP documentation of CDS BDL - InputParameter](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_cp_index_htm/CLOUD/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbdl_action_input_param.htm):

> *The input parameter entity `ParameterEntity` can be a CDS abstract entity or a classic DDIC type*

When I use DDIC Types, the metadata shows that there are no importing parameters. I tried data elements, domains and primitive types, but even though all of them get through the syntax check with none of them the metadata of my service has a importing parameter.

Structures work again, but then again, I would have a structure with only a single attribute to which I would prefer the abstract CDS view.

Is it not possible the use singular DDIC types as parameter? And if it is possible, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,
In behavior definition,

```
static function [fName] parameter [inputParam] result[0..*] [outputParam];
```

eg:

```
static function getUserContactInfo parameter userMasterData result[0..*] userContactInfo ;
```

userMasterData is a structure which might contains userId, UserName or some other keys,
userContactInfo is also a structure, might contains email-addr, telephone, fax no, etc...

and in your inmplementation class,

```
METHODS getUserContactInfo FOR READ IMPORTING userMasterData FOR FUNCTION 
[your rap bo name]~getUserContactInfo RESULT userContactInfo.
```

Comment: my question was how to make it work with basic ddic types, char, int, etc. using structures or abstract entities work just fine for me

Comment: I didn't get your point. is bukrs a singular basic ddic type? if so, I believe static function getCompanyName importing bukrs result[1] butxt; works.

Comment: be careful, even if you use a single domain/data element like bukrs I mentioned above as importing parameter, the rap would also deals it as a table with 2 fields, one is %cid, another is %param, and the %param's type is exactly the importing parameter's type you defined. I hope these info helps.